# Save results of search for use in later operations

Tags: vim

I have some log files that are like this:

```
Foo number: 5551234
Opening file 5551234
Something else with 5551234 in it
1234567 is an entirely different number.
```

Where the "Foo number" is different every time. It can appear in any number of lines, but always has that initial "Foo number: #" line as its first appearance.

I want to replace all instances of this number with the placeholder text "FOO_NUMBER", so that I can diff the logs.

I've been able to match the number using this regex:

```
/\(Foo number: \)\@<=\(\d*\)
```

But I need to save the match from this regex so I can use it in a substitution later. How can I save matched text into a register? Or otherwise re-use the match result after the initial match expression?

Edit: To clarify, the sample file above should look like this after it's all done:

```
Foo number: FOO_NUMBER
Opening file FOO_NUMBER
Something else with FOO_NUMBER in it
1234567 is an entirely different number.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to get the number. If I'd do this interactively, I'd search for an occurrence:

```
/^Foo number: *\zs\d\+
```

Then yank (with `yiw`, `y$`, ...), and put that into the search register:

```
:let @/ = @@
```

Then, because the `:substitute` command defaults to the last used search (register), you can do the replacement like this:

```
:%s//FOO_NUMBER/
```

---

If I'd write a mapping / command, I'd instead grab the number like this:

```
let pattern = '^Foo number: *\zs\d\+'
if search(pattern) > 0
    let number = matchstr(getline('.'), pattern)
    execute '%s/' . number. '/FOO_NUMBER/'
endif
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to replace all instances of this number with the placeholder
>   text "FOO_NUMBER"

```
%s/^Foo number: *\zs\d*/FOO_NUMBER/
```

this will do:

```
Foo number: 5551234 -> Foo number: FOO_NUMBER
```

### Update

now I see what you want to do, you want to first get the number, then replace all the number instances in buffer with the place holder.

Ingo has given a script to do that, you can also do it with macro:

first do search: `/^Foo Number: *\zs\d*`

then press:

```
*qqcwFOO_NUMBER<ESC>n@qq
```

finally replay the macro by: `@q`

it works like:

[image]

short explaination of the macro:

```
*       : search current word, the number
qq      : record macro in reg q
cwFOO.. : change the word with the text
<esc>   : back to the normal mode
n       : go to next word(number)
@q      : call the macro recusively
q       : stop recording
```

Comment: Thanks, but that only replaces the first occurrence of the number. I want to use the first line to determine what the number is, then replace all occurrences throughout the file.

Comment: @JohnSprad just now I misunderstood your requirement, pls see update in answer.